# arm template virtualNetworkName creation appendix issue

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to get a arm template running and have hit an issue with the virtualnetwork creation.

## azuredeploy.json

```
"virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of virtual network to be created"
      },
      "defaultValue": "autohav2VNET"
    },
```

## vnet-net.json

```
"resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('virtualNetworkAddressRange')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": "[parameters('subnets')]"
      }
    }
  ]
```

The issue I am getting is that the vnet gets created with an appendix such as this: autohav2VNETl5g

So when this gets used to create a loadblancer, the names doe not match the defined parameter and the creation fails.

..../virtualNetworks/AUTOHAV2VNET referenced by resource .... /Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/sqlLoadBalancer was not found.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

with the data given it impossible to be sure why this is happening. you are probably passing in a value to the parameter `virtualNetworkName`. because if you wouldn't, than the vnet name would be: `autohav2VNET`.

ARM templates do not append anything anywhere just because they are arm templates. they only do what you designed them to do.

to help with debugging: how you are invoking the template and full template + full parameters file.

Comment: Yes the parameter is being passed, as shown above in the snippet from the azuredeploy.json. If I change this the resultant vnet name is also changed, but when it appears in the Azure console we see the passed name, but with an appendix, in the case of what I have shown above this is l5g, but this varies. That appended characters (l5g) are not in the template that I am using.

Comment: The template (https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/sqlvm-alwayson-cluster) is being initiated by CloudBolt.

That is passing a number of parameters (none of which affect the VNet name) and making the call via Python.

Comment: As it turns out there are failures for the same issue being seen for the template elsewhere:

https://travis-ci.org/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/builds/427389422?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification